# Padding at top of header

Tags: css, wordpress

I have just created a website in wordpress, and pointed it to my domain. Now the website has what looks like a padding on the top of the header. When I try to inspect element, I cannot find the padding anywhere in the styling. Possibly someone with a better understanding could point me in the right direction to look.

My website is at [www.hmsp.ca](http://www.hmsp.ca)

Comment: Is it not on the `body` (or `html`)? `body` by default has some padding (or was it margin)?

Comment: No it is not. I cannot see the styling on that element anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chase,

Take a look at the 562nd line of Framework.css

```
.site-branding {
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
    padding: 1.75em 0;
}
```

That margin line is adding the space at the top,
the .site-branding class is within the `<header>` element, (#masthead > div > div.site-branding). It is adding 1.75em's of space to the top of your page.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. I removed the 1.75em so the margin is just auto 0;

Thank you. I can accept an answer in 4 minutes

Answer (score 2):

The div with the class "site-branding" has a top margin on it that is pushing the header down.